# htaccess Redirect Folder without destroying what's before the folder request

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

Basically I need to redirect a folder with multiple media files stored like: (with a space in the name)

> foo.com/my folder/

to a folder

> foo.com/myfolder/

BUT, as I use multiple PHP functions, that do request those files in the folder, the redirection must also keep requests alive such as:

> other.com/anyfolder/function.php&src=foo.com/my folder/mediaxyz&attribut1&attribut2

A basic redirect I set up was just redirecting every request to foo.com/myfolder, which broke the dynamic function.php requests, hence like:

> other.com/anyfolder/function.php&src=foo.com/**my folder**/mediaxyz&attribut1&attribut2

**not** to:

> other.com/anyfolder/function.php&src=foo.com/**myfolder**/mediaxyz&attribut1&attribut2

but to:

> foo.com/myfolder/mediaxyz&attribut1&attribut2

Will this new redirection work?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^my\ folder/(.*) /myfolder/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

---

**EDIT:**

In the meantime I also tried:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /my\ folder/
RewriteRule ^(.*)/my\ folder/(.*) /myfolder/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

and the same for /my%20folder/ and the REGEX in brackets with native space like "^(.*)/my folder/(.*)"

All redirections simply redirect an incoming link to the base URL, breaking every dynamically created media from function.php.

Comment: Can't you just avoid the use of a name with space. On a unix machine you are basically inviting avoidable trouble by having folders with name.

You can use '-' instead of space in the name.

Comment: yeah,that's what I'm trying to do with the redirection.

However, the folder and around 2k media files have already been installed and got multiple backlinks since 2008. 

I want to get rid of the space and redirect all those files to a folder without a space in the name!

Comment: %20 is used to access the folder with space in the name. May be that's why it isn't working for you.

Comment: This link could have the solution for you. http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3418949.htm

Comment: Actually, I use 2 requests on with \ and one with %20- I'm already aware of that problem. 

I've also already tried using brackets and simply something like "^my folder/$" - however, I need to just redirect that small part of the url, with everything around it left as is.

Thanks for the link though ;)

Comment: The problemis, the redirection is also redirecting the dynamically created files, which need to access those files in the folder. It's no problem to blatantly redirect the folder, however it becoems a problem once I also need to have everything around it untouched...

Comment: It seems like a pickle. Am not sure how'd you take if forward. Typically the sites are structured to divide dynamic and static content in different folders to avoid problems. Would you be able to restructure?

Comment: Well, the only reason I cannot simply put the files into another folder and change the DB paths is that google indexed thousand of them and multiple backlinks to those files in the folder. The moment I simply rename the folder is the moment I get hundreds of 404s. That's why I need to redirect that part. Isn't it possible to JUST redirect that small part instead of redirecting the whole url. Everything I do ends up in redirecting: stuffBEFORE/myfolder/stuffAFTER to basURL/myfolder/stuffAFTER - but I need to keep "stuffBEFORE" alive. It thought that's what (.*) is for.

Comment: As of now, I keep 2 folders alive, because the moment I use the redirects it gives me 404s galore, due to those backlinks, which linked to the dynimacilly created file with the URI variables.