# Delete Query Strings from IMG

Tags: php, .htaccess, timthumb

Well, I've already mentally resigned from this htaccess redirection things. I don't know if most questions I have are not even possible or just nobody knows.

However, now I've a simple question, probably, for someone who is used to do those Apache redirects.

I simply want to redirect

```
 skullbones.jpg&h=200&w=200&q=70&zc=1
```

a timthumb generated img, which gets a wrong incoming link, to:

```
 skullbones.jpg
```

Many bots try to access those img files without the timthumb src path, hence the base URL + the img + the timthumb query strings ending up in 404s.

Would be awesome, if someone could solve at least this case.

Comment: A query should be `skullbones.jpg?h=200&w=200&q=70&zc=1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should fix that.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /(.*)\&(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /%2\? [R,L]
```

The above will change `http://example.com/skullbones.jpg&h=200&w=200&q=70&zc=1` into `http://example.com/skullbones.jpg`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)\&(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /%2\? [R,L]
```

Comment: Nice, will it also work with subdirectories ?

As the image files are not in the base folder. They're in something like /2010/08/

You may can help me with my other problem: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23011967/htaccess-redirect-folder-without-destroying-whats-before-the-folder-request?noredirect=1#comment35186160_23011967)

Comment: Works like a charm, even doesn't interfer with timthumb created pics - great, thanks !

Would be awesome if you could help me with my "[folder redirection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23011967/htaccess-redirect-folder-without-destroying-whats-before-the-folder-request?noredirect=1#comment35186160_23011967)" problem as well.

Comment: MUST take that back... the query is killing the whole wordpress back-end. It works for the images though, but it kills the whole wordpress dashboard inlusively permissions and functions. Just cost me 1 hour to find the origin and it was this htaccess cmd. **I guess it needs some kind of request refinement like "do only if /images/ folder".**

Comment: Try my edit. It will only execute the rewrite if the url has something like `2010/08/` in it

Comment: Nope, does not work, but that's probably due to the URL having more sub-folders than just the date folders, becasue the moment I delete those subfolders in the URL to make it date-only, it redirects the path to the base URL. **The complete folder path is: /folder1/images/year/month/xyz.jpg **

Comment: the problem are the admin dashboard in WP, which uses query strings to ask yourpermissions and stuff...